# Nhibernate bind to DataGridView, insert doesn't work

Tags: nhibernate, datagridview

To bind an NHibernate class to a DataGridView I do:

```
IList<DatabaseAccess.poco.Employee> employees =
                (from e in session.Linq<DatabaseAccess.poco.Employee>() select e).ToList<DatabaseAccess.poco.Employee>();

this.employeeBindingSource.DataSource = employees;
```

And when I commit, only changes on rows that already exist in the database are sent, using the grid to create a new row doesn't work.

So, can I expect that binding a list to `DataSource` is enough and I don't have to create Employee object and do `session.Save(new_employee);`? Or is it a must?

I haven't found any tutorial that describes a full DataGridView bind along with creating new rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's a must. DataGridView has no knowledge about NH and NH has no knowledge that DataGridView added a new row. So you must, for example, in UserAddedRow event handler save new entity.

```
using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(albumBindingSource.Current);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Until you close session NH keeps track of every retrieved into session cache entity. When you call ITransaction.Commit() NH updates all modified entities.

Comment: After commit I get:Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

In page_load method, Is your datagrid bind in IsPostBack.

like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Grid Bind
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't use Asp.Net. Only Winforms

Comment: first, you must confirm insert operation work. if insert doesn't work.Is your session.Save(new_employee)  method add transaction attribute? like this [Transaction(TransactionMode.Requires)]

Comment: insert only works on the grid. i can add new records, but nothing is sent to the database after commit. update works.

Comment: i didn't use session.Save(...). I was thinking that grid do this for me. Like it works for update operation.

Comment: in nhibernate, insert,update,delete operation should in a transaction. Especially after these operation having select.

Comment: if insert has transaction. I think database should has update data.